# Pouchdb query returns 401 unauthorized error

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

This is probably a noob problem. I'm trying to run a simple query on a public database, but it returning this error:

```js
401: unauthorized - with a message - "You are not a db or server admin."
```

I'm logged in as a user (not an admin) when this happens, but the same user can create entries in that database using the pouchdb API. (I'm using pouchdb-authentication to handle login, sessions, etc..)

I'm probably doing this all wrong, but here's my query code:

```js
var map = function(doc) {
emit(doc.grade); };

app.db.query(map, function(err, response) {  
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
    }

    if (response) {
     console.log(response);
    }
 });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB requires admin permissions to add map/reduce indexes, which is what PouchDB attempts to do if you explicitly specify a map/reduce function when calling query().

Instead, define your indexes as an admin and have your code reference the index by name.